# Error when using GridView1_SelectedIndexChanged

Tags: c#, asp.net, events, gridview

I have i Gridview with selectedindexchanged event and 3 buttons. when 1 of the buttons is clicked i use the
**GridView1.SelectedRow.RowIndex** to optain the selected row.

[image]

This works fine when the user has clicked on a row. But the problem is when No rows are selected and **GridView1.SelectedRow.RowIndex** is called in my code.
This gives the error: **Object reference not set to an instance of an object.**

Any ideas how i can check whether GridView1.SelectedRow.RowIndex has a value or how i can disable it until a row is selected?

Here is the code for add button:

```
protected void AddNews_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    rowIndex = GridView1.SelectedRow.RowIndex;
    Response.Redirect("~/AddNews.aspx?Parameter=" + rowIndex);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
protected void AddNews_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    int i = GridView1.SelectedRow.RowIndex;
    if(i>= 0)
    {
        Response.Redirect("~/AddNews.aspx?Parameter=" + index);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can have your NewsID bind to your hyper link:

```
         <asp:HyperLinkField 
                        Text="Add News"
                        HeaderText="" 
    DataNavigateUrlFormatString="~/AddNews.aspx?Parameter=/{0}" 
                        DataNavigateUrlFields="NewsID" >
                        <ItemStyle HorizontalAlign="Left" />
                    </asp:HyperLinkField>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
protected void AddNews_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    int index = GridView1.SelectedIndex;
    if(index >= 0) // if -1 no selection 
    {
        Response.Redirect("~/AddNews.aspx?Parameter=" + index);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are getting the `NullReferenceException` because `GridView1.SelectedRow` is null. Verify that `GridView1.SelectedRow` is **not** null before you attempt to use it.

```
if(GridView1.SelectedRow != null)
{
     // A row is selected, SelectedRow is not null so safe to access RowIndex...
     int rowIndex = GridView1.SelectedRow.RowIndex;
}
```

Alternatively, you can just use `SelectedRowIndex` member which returns `-1` when nothing is selected.

```
if(GridView1.SelectedIndex >= 0)
{
     // A row is selected, get SelectedRowIndex...
     int rowIndex = GridView1.SelectedIndex;
}
```

Comment: Actually, it is not (look again)... I think your down vote is totally not merited here. BTW - Your code does not compile.